# NLogSpace and CoNLogSpace

Tags: computational-complexity

Assume S1, S2∈ NLOGSPACE. Which of the following statements is true?
• S1 \ S2 ∈ coNLOGSPACE
• S1 Δ S2 ∈ NLOGSPACE

where A\B is the set of members of A that are not members of B. And A Δ B is the set of members of A U B that are not members of A ∩ B

Comment: Try to show us what you have tried instead of making it look like you are giving us a homework assignment.

Comment: since NLogSpace=CoNLogSpace, i think both the statements are true... but is is true to say that ConNLogSpace=NLogSpace??

Answer (score 1):

The [Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem&oldid=463703680) says that NLOGSPACE is closed under complementation.  So, if S1 and S2 are in NLOGSPACE, S1 \ S2 = S1 ∩ S2$^c$ and S1 Δ S2 = (S1 ∩ S2$^c$) ∪ (S1$^c$ ∩ S2) are both in NLOGSPACE.  Since NLOGSPACE is closed under complementation, NLOGSPACE=co-NLOGSPACE, so they are also in co-NLOGSPACE.  The link contains a sketch of a proof of the Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem.

Comment: so that means both the statements are true?